# What is the most reliable method to optimize linear objective function with nonlinear constraints and Why?

Tags: optimization, scipy, nlopt

I currently solve the following problem:

[image]

Basically, this problem is equivalent to find the confidence interval for logistic regression. The objective function is **linear** (no second derivative), meanwhile, the constraint is non-linear. Specifically, I used n = 1, alpha = 0.05, theta = logit of p where p = [0,1] (for detail, please see binomial distribution). Thus, I have a closed-form solution for the gradient and jacobian for objective and constraints respectively.

In R, I first tried the alabama::auglag function which used augmented Lagrangian method with BFGS (as a default) and nloptr::auglag function which used augmented Lagrangian method with SLSQP (i.e. SLSQP as a local minimizer). Although they were able to find the (global) minimizer most time, sometimes they failed and produced a far-off solution.
After all, I could obtain the best (most stable) result using SLSQP method (nloptr::nloptr with algorithm=NLOPT_LD_SLSQP).

Now, I have a question of why SLSQP produced better result in this setting than the first two methods and why the first two methods (augmented Lagrangian with BFGS and SLSQP as a local optimizer) did not perform well.
Another question is, considering my problem setting, what would be the best method to find the optimizer?

Any comments and suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: These are not the most sophisticated NLP solvers. If you can state the problem in GAMS or AMPL, you can try out a few much more advanced NLP solver at [NEOS server](https://neos-server.org/neos/index.html). In addition, these tools give you automatic differentiation.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Greatly appreciate the suggestion. Indeed, I focus on "why" and the rationale behind the current method (SLSQP) rather than obtaining the solution because SLSQP produced satisfactory output for every case I have. Also, with closed-form (differentiable) objective function, and constraint(s), calculating/approximating gradient/Jacobian is not a concern.

Comment: Never use finite differences, unless absolutely needed, This increases the number of function evaluations and you lose half of the precision. This is a very bad practice. Automatic differentiation is a lifesaver for larger, more complex models (this is not one of them).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Either I totally misunderstood what you meant or I did not clarify myself enough here (due to word, "approximate"). As far as I know, the finite difference method is to "approximate" for solving partial differential equations. However, in my problem, I know the exact form of first-order (say our objective function is x^2 then I can just use 2x for gradient). Thus, you can think what I did in my work was a kind of symbolic differentiation, which may be equivalent to the automatic differentiation
 - continued -

Comment: (also I want to mention that I carefully constructed all equations considering some numerical issues such as catastrophic cancellation, etc). I know this is not practical (most time) but my problem happens to have all closed-form solutions for n-th derivatives. Besides, I was able to obtain a more stable output when I use the symbolic differentiation than an automatic differentiation that I tested with nl.grad() and nl.jacobian() from nlotpr package in R.